# My C++ DLL fails to compile except when I first open the project (in Netbeans)

Tags: c++, netbeans, dll, build

I have a C++ DLL, something I have used several times. I use Netbeans, with MinGW.

I'm not sure when this began happening exactly, I made some small changes to the code and then began having problems. Basically, I can open Netbeans, open the project, execute a Clean and Build, and it passes, creating the DLL. However, if I try and do it again, it passes the clean, but fails the build. Here's the output from when it fails the second Clean and Build.

```
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `absolute path here...'
rm -f -r build/Release
rm -f dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/myfile.dll
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `absolute path here...'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `absolute path here...'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/myfile.dll
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `absolute path here...'
mkdir -p build/Release/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Release/MinGW-Windows/Main.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `absolute path here...'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `absolute path here...'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Along with this, my DLL which had been executing without errors in my external program, now will not execute at all. I can't help but think the two issues are related. If I run it more times, I'll get a different message, which seems highly unusual...it cant execute a rm command?

```
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf

make.exe[1]: Entering directory `absolute path here...'
rm -f -r build/Release
make.exe[1]: rm: Command not found
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `absolute path here...'
make.exe[1]: *** [.clean-conf] Error 127
make.exe": *** [.clean-impl] Error 2

CLEAN FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

If you need more information let me know, I'm pretty lost here so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`rm` and `mkdir` are normally unix commands that have to be added to the PATH to make them work on windows.

Try going to the control panel, search for "environment" to open the environment panel and edit the PATH to add the directory for rm.exe and mkdir.exe (I am guessing `C:\msys\1.0\bin`).

After that you probably want to restart netbeans and any cmd shells you have open.

Comment: Adding the path to the environment variables is part of the steps required to setup MinGW, and I have done already. This doesn't address the issue where it is able to build the first time, but unable to in subsequent attempts, without restarting Netbeans. As you can see from the first block, the CLEAN is successful, and it uses the rm unix command as well.

Comment: The path is obviously correct where it can find the rm and mkdir (unless errors are being suppressed here)  and incorrect when it fails. Something about the Makefile running a submake is affecting the path and therefore the systems ability to find these commands. I would check the path again,  try running the makefile from the command prompt. It would seem to be more of a mys/mingw issue than a netbeans issue. All netbeans should need to do is execute make and make should always be able to execute rm and mkdir as needed.